# Access to Excel formula

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
CountFormula = "=COUNTIFS('Resource Forecast by Month'!A3:A13,Analysis!A" & Val(strRow) & ",'Resource Forecast by Month'!B3:B13," & strCol & "2,'Resource Forecast by Month'!C3:C13,D1)"
```

I'm using MS Access to write this formula to a range of cells in a spreadsheet. I'm changing the value of the column and the row of respective cells (using `strRow` and `StrCol`). The error message is

> "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

What is wrong here?

Comment: How are you assigning strRow and StrCol? What are their values when you crash, click Debug and hover over the vars? What does Debug.Print show as the formula?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.  Problem was that the client had provided the incorrect sheetname. So problem solved.  Thanks again